# MVC Enum Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to list an enum in my Razor DropDownList. My model's property is :

```
public gender gender { get; set; }
```

Here is my view code :

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.gender, new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(gender))),new { @class="form-control"})
```

The list works but the jQuery Validation error message is *The field Gender must be a number*.

How can I solve it ?

Thanks

Answer (score 4):

This is how you can achieve with `**Enum**` :

Model :

```
 public enum Genders
 {
            [Display(Name = "Male")]
            M = 1,
            [Display(Name = "Female")]
            N = 2            
 }
 public Genders Gender { get; set; }
```

View :

```
@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.Gender, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Comment: Enum achieve in ef designer (edmx) enum types

Comment: what if you put below code in your `.cshtml` instead your code.

`@Html.EnumDropDownListFor(x => x.Gender, "Please Select", new { @class = "form-control" })`

What error you have got ? Is it working or not ?

Comment: Not working error message Return type 'System.Int32' is not supported.

Comment: Can you post the values of `Enum gender ` ??

Comment: doesnt post value

Comment: @FurkanBozdağ , I mean can you please show me the code for `Enum gender` ??

Comment: @FurkanBozdağ, it it was not integer then my code will definately work. But you should see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15898171/c-sharp-mvc-dropdownlistfor-bind-a-enum-to-a-integer-model-field) for answer.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Model

```
public int gender { get; set; }
```

Controller

```
public enum selectgender{
...
}

ViewBag.selectgender= Enum.GetValues(typeof(selectgender)).Cast<selectgender>();
```

View

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.gender, new SelectList(ViewBag.selectgender), "Select Gender",new { @class = "form-control" })
```

Answer (score 2):

Update 2020...

Add an enum type, gender, to the model.

```
public enum GenderType
{
    Male,
    Female,
    Other
}
public GenderType Gender { get; set; }
```

In view, do this...

```
<select asp-for="Gender" asp-items="@Html.GetEnumSelectList<GenderType>()">
```